# Magento Api with SOAP

Tags: product, api, soap

I want to get ONE random product from the productlist of a category. The product must have "status=1".

Is it possible?

Thx.

Comment: every thing is possible my friend

Comment: by query twice, list and get random of it. then get product.

Comment: You need to extend the API, just search for Magento Custom API and you will come across various resources explaining how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to refine your product with status attribute filter.

```
$mydata['id'] it specified the category id's array.

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                             ->getCollection()
                             ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('eq' =>$mydata['id'][$key]))
->addAttributeToFilter('status','1')
                         ->getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

## I think It is Proper way for you.

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // select all attributes
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
->addStoreFilter($storeId);

$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');

$collection->setPageSize(1) // limit number of results returned
    ->setCurPage(0)
    ->load()
    ;
```